# DHT22 Sensor's checksum not valid

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded, sensors

The read bits from DHT22 sensor as follow:

0000000111010001000000001110111111101111

If we calculate the check sum of them by the formula that they gave:
[image]

Reference: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/Digital+humidity+and+temperature+sensor+AM2302.pdf

If you convert each of their octets in the example to decimal and compare it with the last 8 bits (checksum) - they are equal.

```
Binary:      Decimal:
00000001     1     //First  8 bits
11010001     209   //Second 8 bits
00000000     0     //Third  8 bits
11101111     239   //Fourth 8 bits
---------------------------------->
Summed:      449
------------ Not equal ----------->
11000001     193   //Check sum
```

When the 16 bits for the Humidity and 16 bits for Temperature are converted they show correct results based on other popular DHT22 libraries, but the checksum is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

I misunderstood the formula that they have given.
By last 8 bits they mean the last 8 bits of the 4 octets sum:

```
Binary:                       Decimal:
00000001                      1     //First  8 bits
11010001                      209   //Second 8 bits
00000000                      0     //Third  8 bits
11101111                      239   //Fourth 8 bits
---------------------------------->
Summed:                       449
449 as Binary:                111000001
449's last 8 bits:            11000001
11000001 as decimal:          193
----------------------------- Equal ----------->
11000001                      193   //Check sum
```

I hope someone who had the same problem came to that, because it took me hours of experimenting to find what was causing the problem.

In their example their sum is also lower that 255 and it is even harder to catch it, because you doesn't need to remove a bit, because the value is no bigger than 8 bits.

Comment: Indeed.  Checksums are always a fixed but width.  This simply means that the overflow is ignored.  The idiomatic implementation is simply sum the octets into a `uint8_t` accumulator.